# Why MongoDB $expr is not working properly?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

```js
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "follows",
        let: {
            id: "$_id",
        },
        as: "friend",
        pipeline: [
            {
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $or: [
                            {
                                $and: [{ follower: "$$id" }, { following: Types.ObjectId(userId) }],
                            },
                            {
                                $and: [{ follower: Types.ObjectId(userId) }, { following: "$$id" }],
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

This code above always returns every single data from the "Follow" collection. Even if I use more simple query inside $expr like

```js
$expr: {
  follower: Types.ObjectId(userId),
}
```

It still returns the same data! But this simpler query works fine without $expr.

Here is my database model and expected result from my first query.

```
db.follow [
    {
        _id: abc123,
        follower: '1',
        following: '2'
    },
    {
        _id: abc124,
        follower: '2',
        following: '1'
    },
    {
        _id: abc125,
        follower: '3',
        following: '4'
    }
]

result.friend [
    {
        _id: abc123,
        follower: '1',
        following: '2'
    },
    {
        _id: abc124,
        follower: '2',
        following: '1'
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data to test the corrected query on? The problem is probably caused by you directly passing field names to your `$expr`statement instead of using it inside an `$eq` operator. In your case I think you don't even need `$expr` operator. One additional thing: You are trying to concat different statements using `$and`. It seems like the values passed to different statements are different. Therefore it seems like `$and` could never fulfill all statements and will therefore never match. Can you provide some expected result from the data you provide as an example?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand what you mean, but if it causes any error or doesn't fulfil the query, then it should return no data. Why it always returns full collection of data? Moreover the simpler version of the query I attached, It also returns wrong data.

Comment: @FabianStrathaus I have added my expected result as well as the database model.

Answer (score 0):

First of all let's target your simple query

```
$expr: {
  follower: Types.ObjectId(userId),
}
```

This does not work since `$expr` does not know how to compare the database attribute with the provided ObjectId. You should include `$eq` operator to check vor equality:

```
$expr: {
  $eq: [
    "$follower",
    Types.ObjectId(userId)
  ]
}
```

If you are checking for equality you don't actually need `$expr` operator, but can just pass the field and value to your `$match` query like this:

```
$match: {
  "follower": Types.ObjectId(userId)
}
```

**Update after sample data is provided:**
To query your data as needed you can just use `$or` to find matching documents fulfilling *at least one* of your conditions.

```
$match: {
  $or: [
    {
      follower: "1"
    },
    {
      following: "1"
    }
  ]
}
```